# Avoid leaving personal data when you quit your job

Tags: data-recovery, data-transfer, cleaning, disk-cleanup, personal-data

I'm starting working on a new job soon and will be given a corporate laptop. Besides work projects, there will be some my personal data footprint like logged in email, messengers, personal documents and so on.

How do you keep your data separated on a corporate workplace so in case you quit you can have no data left on your work computer?

How do you feel you have some of your personal data on a work computer?

Answer (score 1):

For my work laptop, I use Chrome as my browser. This means that I can easily remove my user profile when it is time for me to give my work laptop back. If for any reason that I am not able to log out of my laptop, I can then [log out remotely from another computer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9159867?hl=en-GB). As for documents, I can keep those in onedrive, Google docs etc and this will also be logged out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! A good way to go